# Como mostrar el proceso de una cuenta en python?

Tags: python

me darian una mano con este ejercicio en Python?
no se como descomponer los pasos para mostrarlo asi al resultado:

Escribir un programa que lea dos enteros de tres dígitos e imprima su producto en el
siguiente formato:

```
 325

x 426
-----

1950
650
1300
138450
```

Entiendo como hacer la multiplicacion, agregarle la X y el "_____", lo que no se es como imprimir el paso a paso de la multiplicacion numero x numero. les agradezco, hasta ahora estoy asi:

```
entero1 = int((input("Ingrese un entero de tres digitos: ")))
entero2 = int((input("Ingrese otro entero de tres digitos: ")))
print(entero1)
print ("X")
print(entero2)
print('-----')
```

Comment: `entero2 = [int(x) for x in input("Ingrese otro entero de tres digitos: ")]` deja en `entero2` la lista de los digitos enteros que componen el número ingresado. Multiplica `entero1` por cada digito (agregando los ceros que corresponda) y suma los resultados.

Comment: aah entonces habria que pasar la variable entero2 a un tipo lista, ahi entendi, muchisimas gracias!